# Socket.IO emits multiple times in a room (Using with React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I have a react app that allows multiple users to join a room and then the server picks a user randomly and then send the username of the selected user to everyone in the room. But the problem is that the server emits the same event multiple times(the number of emits is equal to the number of users in the room).

This is the code from the server that emits the event:

```
socket.on("selectNextPlayer", roomid => {
        const selectedIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*rooms[roomid].participants.length);
        const selectedUsername = rooms[roomid].participants[selectedIndex];
        io.to(roomid).emit("setSelectedPlayer",selectedUsername); // THIS EVENT
        connectedUsers[selectedUsername].emit("myTurn");
    })
```

This is the code in the react client that listens for the event:

```
const socket = socketIOClient("http://127.0.0.1:8080");

useEffect(() => {
        if(isRoomOwner){
            socket.emit("createNewRoom", username,roomid);
        }else {
            socket.emit("joinNewRoom", username,roomid);
        }

        //Get all participants
        socket.on("allParticipants", (allparticipants, roomOwner) => {
            setParticipants(allparticipants);
            setOwner(roomOwner);
        })
        //Start/Stop Game
        socket.on("gameStatusChanged", gameStatus => {
            setGameStarted(gameStatus);
            //Select Next Player
            socket.emit("selectNextPlayer",roomid);
        })
        //set selected player
        socket.on("setSelectedPlayer", selectedPlayer => { //HERE
            setSelectedPlayer(selectedPlayer);
            setChats(prevChats => ([...prevChats,`Next player is ${selectedPlayer}`]))
        })
        //On my turn show truth/dare buttons
        socket.on("myTurn", () => {
            setIsMyTurn(true);
        })
    },[]);
```

The problem is that the element `Next player is ${selectedPlayer}` is added multiple times to the `chats` array which is stored in a state.

I tried moving `const socket = socketIOClient("http://127.0.0.1:8080");` to another file and importing it at the top using `import {socket} from '../services/socket';` this didn't work.

Edit: (Thanks to @Tushar)

selectNextPlayer is getting called multiple times.

```
socket.on("gameStatusChanged", gameStatus => {
            setGameStarted(gameStatus);
            //Select Next Player
            socket.emit("selectNextPlayer",roomid);
        })
```

This function call emits the selectNextPlayer function. This function listens for the gameStatusChanged event and calls emits a new selectNextPlayer function.

```
socket.on("startGame", roomid => {
        console.log("SELECT START GAME CALLED");
        io.to(roomid).emit("gameStatusChanged", true);
    })
```

This event emits the gameStatusChanged event but this is getting called only once. So why is selectNextPlayer getting called multiple times ?

Comment: How is gameStatusChanged called. Check if it is only called once. You can add a console above inside your `selectNextPlayer` to confirm it is called once.

Comment: @TusharShahinOh yes selectNextPlayer is being called multple time

Comment: Is that what you want? Because that is the event triggering your erranous emit.

Comment: @TusharShahi Just a sec Let me update the question

Comment: @TusharShahi I edited the question Pls check it now

Comment: `gameStatusChanged` is in your client right? So its handler will be called for all your clients. Then each of these handlers will emit `selectNextPlayer` to the server. You can either this directly when you are emitting `gameStatusChanged`  or you can have a flag that ensures `selectNextPlayer` event handler is called only first time in the server.

Comment: Ya just fixed that the button that starts the game emits the startGame event should also emit the selectNextPlayer event so instead of putting socket.emit("selectNextPlayer",roomid) from the button click handler, I put it in the on("gameStatusChanged") event handler which caused the issue.....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
socket.on("gameStatusChanged", gameStatus => {
    setGameStarted(gameStatus);
    //Select Next Player
    socket.emit("selectNextPlayer",roomid);
})
```

is on the client-side so for every client the `"selectNextPlayer"` event is emmited. So to fix this move `socket.emit("selectNextPlayer",roomid);` this to somewhere else for me it was  to move it to the same examct event handler which emiits the `startGame` event.

```
{
                username == owner && !gameStarted &&
                <button 
                    onClick={() => {
                        socket.emit("startGame",roomid);
                        socket.emit("selectNextPlayer", roomid);
                    }}
                >
                    Start Game
                </button>
            }
```